# Enable history in gnome terminal in apricity os

Tags: arch-linux, terminal, gnome, command-history, session

I can't make gnome terminal or any other terminal remember the commands history.
Every time I close the terminal and reopen it I can't access previous commands (usually done with the up arrow key).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally did it!
Apricity OS uses **Zsh** as shell and to enable history you have to edit the file `~/.zshrc` and make it look like below:

```
source /usr/share/zsh/site-contrib/powerline.zsh
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select
bindkey "^R" history-incremental-pattern-search-backward
HISTSIZE=10000
SAVEHIST=10000
HISTFILE=~/.zsh_history
```